# Access to object and set it null throw element of array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Very simple example:

```
var a = { id: 5 };
var b = { id: 6 };
var c = { id: 7 };
var arr = [a, b, c];
```

Now i have a function:

```
function remove(startIndex) {
  // set objects to null from startIndex in array
}
```

If i try this:

```
arr[0] = null;
```

then i have:

```
arr[0] == null // true
a == null // false (i need true)
```

So, my question, how could i access to object throw any collection (array or object) and change it?

I don't want to write something like this:

```
function remove(startIndex) {
  if(startIndex == 0) { 
    a = null;
    b = null;
    c = null;
  }
  if(startIndex == 1) {
    b = null;
    c = null;
  }
  if(startIndex == 2) {
    c = null;
  }
}
```

much easier to write like this (but it doesn't work):

```
function remove(startIndex) {
  for(var i = startIndex; i<arr.length; i++) arr[i] = null;
}
```

Comment: here's an even simpler example: `a=5; b=a; b=99` - what would be `a`?

Comment: Will you *always* access variables `a,b,c`, or will you assign their values to other variables -- other than the array i.e.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you're aiming with this code you're writing, but here's how Javascript works:

Every time you instantiate a variable with a value, say an object like `{ id: 10 }`. That object is stored in memory and a *reference* is returned back to your variable, say you name it `a`.

Now, if you say `var b = a;`, the same reference is now passed on to variable `b`. Now Javascript runtime knows you have two variables referencing the object `{ id: 10 }`.

You now no longer want to keep the variable `b`, so you write `b = null;`. You think the object is deleted, but the Javascript runtime knows the object `{ id: 10 }` has *one* reference -- i.e. the variable `a` -- referencing it. So it won't remove `{ id: 10 }` from memory.

However, if you also write `a = null;`, then there are *Zero* references, and the Javascript runtime's [Garbage Collector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) will eventually get to removing the object from memory.

All this was to get you to understand that without further housekeeping, you will not be able to achieve what you're hoping to do.

If you really want `a, b, c` to be `null`, you will have to write some code that explicitly sets their value to `null` too. Like `a = arr[0]; b = arr[1]; c = arr[2];` whenever the array is changed. You can `eval` the statements and do some string templating to not write the variables by hand etc., and make a loop out of that, but that's not worth it if you only have three variables.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript doesn't have pointers, so to achieve what you want in the original way will not work.

Other than `arr[0] = null`, you can try setting `a` to `null` directly as well.

Comment: I can't do it directly

Comment: @FSou1 why are you unable to? do you mind elaborating on that in your question?

Comment: I described why i'm unable to do that in `function remove` and why i should access to objects exactly throw index and not directly

Comment: @FSou1 okay, sorry for that then, I have no idea how to do so. I suggest you look at Mutahhir's answer which gives a full explanation of why you can't or wait till someone can give you a suitable answer. :)